# Vectors and integers e.t.c

Tags: vector

Anybody can help me with cpp exercise?
Here is the the code that i should write:

Read a set of integers into a vector. Print the sum of each pair of adjacent elements.
Change your program so that it prints the sum of the first and second elements,
followed by the sum of the second and third elements, and same continue to--last, and so on.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Sorry! I meant here i have to write a code which description is: Read a set of integers into a vector. Print the sum of each pair of adjacent elements.
Change your program so that it prints the sum of the first and second elements,
followed by the sum of the second and third elements, and same continue to--last, and so on.

Comment: Yes, that is the assignment text, which is already in the question body. Please tell us what have you tried so far. What has been your reasoning? How would you approach the problem? Did you try some code? Did you put any effort in solving the assignment by yourself?

Comment: This is what I have found so far

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> #include <iostream>
> #include <vector>
>
> using namespace std;
>
> int main()
> {
>    vector<int> myvector;
>    int num_entra = 0;
>
>    while (cin >> num_entra)
>        myvector.push_back(num_entra);
>
>
>    cout << "Sum of adjacent pairs: " << endl;
>    for (auto it = myvector.begin(); it != myvector.end() - 1; ++it)
>    {
>        *it += *(it + 1);
>        cout << *it << ' ';
>    }
>
>    return 0;
> }
> ```